# Zoom disconnects Wi-Fi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, zoom-meeting

I am a student and I join to some classes via `Zoom` these days. Most of my teachers use **free accounts** hence it disconnects us every 40 minutes. The problem is when it happens my Wi-Fi connection also disconnects and asks for the password to re-connect. Can someone explain what causes this to happen and how to avoid it?

P.S.: I use my personal laptop which runs Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit unusual. I am involved in lots of Zoom calls and Wireless does not disconnect when Zoom closes. My colleagues are predominantly using Windows 10.

Look through this Zoom article below. One key recommendation was to upgrade your Router Firmware.

Also try a wired (Ethernet) connection.

[Zoom support for wireless issues](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362463-Wireless-WiFi-Connection-Issues)

> Try to connect directly via Wired (if your internet router has wired
> ports)
>
> Upgrade your WiFI router firmware. Check your WiFi router vendor
> support site for firmware upgrade availability.
>
> Turn off your corporate VPN if it's not required for the meeting

If you think the computer is at fault, try resetting TCP/IP:

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

(2) ipconfig /flushdns

(3) restart the computer

That may help in this situation. Also try the Wired Ethernet connection in case there is some issue with your wireless connection.

Comment: I know this looks very strange. That's why I posted this question here. There is no new firmware updates available to the router. I don't use VPN either. What might be the problem?

Comment: There were a number of suggestions in the article I posted (about a dozen) . I have not seen this and the people I work with have not reported this either. Work through all the possibilities and then see if you can use another connection to test (phone hotspot for example).

Comment: I'll try. Also... I don't get this problem if use either my brother's or father's laptop which also use the same Wi-Fi network. It may suggest that the problem is not with the router. Can it be some kind of virus or conflict caused by another program?

Comment: It is always worthwhile to scan for viruses so try that. If only Zoom, viruses seem a bit less likely but still scan for them.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I'll try doing as you told.

Comment: Since it may be the machine itself (that is also somewhat strange) try resetting TCP/IP .   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: Also (and I mentioned again in my answer) try an Ethernet connection.